# How to generate json response from python?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am making an API call from Python. My current code is supposed to generate a JSON response, but throws out a Response code 500 (Internal Server Error). However, when I generate the data using the API's built in extract tool, it returns the data. Code snippet is as follows:

```
def Performance(data):
BASEURL = 'https://api-c31.ict.com/inContactAPI/'
accessToken = (data["access_token"])

#Check if accessToken is empty or null
if accessToken!= "":



#Give necessary parameters for http request
    payload={'startDate':'1/1/2020', 
    'endDate':'1/6/2020',
    'fields':'"agentId","teamId","totalHandled"'}

#add all necessary headers
    header_param = { 'User-Agent' : 'Chrome/79.0.3945.117',
                 'Authorization': 'bearer ' + '{accessToken}',
                 'content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                 'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*'
                  }

# Make get http request
   response_1 = requests.get(BASEURL + 'services/{version}/agents/performance' , headers = header_param, params=payload) 
   #answer1.raise_for_status

#print response appropriately
    print (response_1)

#response 
else: print('error')
```

response_1 generates  a Response 500. How can I generate the data from Python?

Comment: The status code 500 means there was an error on the server side, so your code probably raised an exception. What do your logs show?

Comment: I'm assuming the *request* is suppose to send the parameters as a JSON object? *Your* code doesn't generate a response; it *receives* a response from the HTTP server you send the request to.

Comment: @chepner correct. The get request receives a response. Sorry for weird phrasing. kaya3 - the logs just show that the code ran and the output is simply response 500

Comment: Is `{version}` supposed to be replaced by an actual version number or tag? Same with `{accessToken}`; it looks like you forgot to use f-strings, e.g., `f'services/{version}/...'`.

Comment: @chepner, having made a change to {version}, I now see an error for "name access_token not defined" However, the Response 500 error is no longer showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` doesn't encode your payload as JSON; `json` does.

```
response_1 = requests.get(
                 BASEURL + 'services/{version}/agents/performance',
                 headers=header_param,
                 json=payload)
```

Comment: it didn't make a difference, it is still returning a 500 response

Comment: Do you really need the double quotes in the `fields` value?